# Jquery checkbox checked after clicking one checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have one table.Inside table I have two `<td>`.First `<td>` has one checkbox and second `<td>` has sections which also contains checkboxes.Onclick of checkbox of first `<td>`,it should check all the checkboxes of other `<td>`.This is the code which is using datatable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tmpColumns.length; i++) {
            var obj = new Object();
            var table = "";
            obj.title = tmpColumns[i].toUpperCase();
            obj.data = tmpColumns[i];
            obj.defaultContent = "";
            columns.push(obj);
            if(type == "table" && i == 0) {
                obj.render = function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    table = row.name;
                    select = '<section> <label class="checkbox" style="padding-left: 1em;"><input type="checkbox" id = "checkAll" " data-table-name="' + table + '">'  + table + ' <i></i></label></section>';
                    return select;

                }
            }

            if(type == "table" && i == 1) {
                obj.render = function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    table = row.name;

                    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                        var column = table + "." + data[j];
                        ele = ele + '<section> <label class="checkbox" style="padding-left: 1em;"><input type="checkbox" class="addToQuery" data-col="' + column + '" data-table="' + table + '"><i></i>' + data[j] + '</label></section>';
                    }
                    return ele;
                };
                break;
            }
        }
```

This is the code for checking checkbox after clicking first  checkbox.

```
$("#tableList").on("change",'input[data-table-name]', function () {

        var bool = $(this).prop('checked');     
        var tableName = $(this).attr("data-table-name");
        $('input[data-table="' + tableName + '"]').prop("checked", bool);
    });
```

I want to check the particular checkbox in which is in the same `<tr>`.But it is checking all the `<tr>` elements
Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('input[data-table="' + tableName + '"]').prop("checked", bool);` Bettter to post generated markup too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tableList").on("change",'input[data-table-name]', function () {   
    $(this).closest("tr").find('input[data-table="' + tableName + '"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```